# Proper scope for App Engine services

Tags: java, google-app-engine, design-patterns, scope

**What is the proper scope** for App Engine services when creating a servlet: static, instance, or local?  And **what are the implications of each**?  It seems like you should want to use them in as wide a scope as possible, to avoid the overhead of re-creating (or re-retrieving) them, but I wonder as to whether this will cause improper reuse of data, especially if `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>`.

---

Examples of each scope are provided below.  [`MemcacheService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService) will be used in the examples below, but my question applies to any and all services (though I'm not sure if the answer depends on the service being used).  I commonly use [`MemcacheService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService), [`DatastoreService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService), [`PersistenceManager`](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/PersistenceManager.html), [`ChannelService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/channel/ChannelService), and [`UserService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService).

**Static scope:**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        memcacheService.get("x");
    }
}
```

**Instance member:**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        memcacheService.get("x");
    }
}
```

**Local scope:**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
        memcacheService.get("x");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAE is a distributed system where all of it's services run on separate servers. So when you invoke a service it internally serializes the request (afaik with protocol buffers) sends it to the server running the service, retrieves the result and deserializes it.

So all of `*Service` classes are basically pretty thin wrappers around serialization/deserialization code. See for example [source of MemcacheService](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java).

About scope: there is no need to optimize on `*Service` classes as they are pretty thin wrappers and creating them should take negligible time compared to whole service roundtrip.

Comment: Complete, succinct answer, with source to back it up.  Thanks.

Comment: Right, but it still makes sense to make them fields to be able to mock them in unit-tests.